# Need another eye to look at a solution.

Tags: integration

So I'm going on double integrals and I'm understanding how to solve them. But I've come across a particular answer and reviewing a solution to the problem. The problem is our solution is the same all the way down to the very last part. Here is the answer to the problem $2\ln 7+2\ln 3$.

Here is the double integral.

$$\int_{0}^{20}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{y}{x+1}dydx$$

Can anybody explain how $2\ln 7+2\ln 3$ is being derived?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\frac{y}{x+1}=y\frac{1}{x+1}$, and $\frac{1}{x+1}$ is independent of $y$ and may be pulled out of the inner integral.

Comment: @vadim123 I already know how to do the integral and solve. But my final answer once we get to solving for the last set of bounds(i.e., 0 to 20) does not match the solution I'm reading. I come to the answer 2ln(21).

Comment: Then you're done, because $\ln (xy) = \ln x + \ln y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're missing that $$2\log (21)=2\log (7\cdot 3)=2\left(\log (7)+\log(3)\right)$$

Comment: whoops you're right! Thanks you!

Comment: @John Carpenter No problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{20}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{y}{x+1}dydx=\int_{0}^{20}\frac{dx}{x+1}\int_{0}^{2}ydy=\left[\log(1+x)\right]_0^{20}\times \left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_0^2=2\log(21)=2\log(7\times3)=2\log7+2\log3$$

Comment: I aleady had the right answer in 2ln(21) I just wasn't think about the fact that 2ln(21)=2ln(7)+2ln(3). Thanks though

Comment: @JohnCarpenter You're welcome.